# Why is the container too small to house the grid items?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm a newbie in web development. Currently I'm working on a design where i decided to use the grid layout module but I don't  know why the container doesn't houses the grid items correctly.The container is very small and my CSS code produces a visual unappealing output. Here is the  image of what I wanted to achieve [image: My Goal].Here's what i achieved with the grid container given a blue color.[image: My code output].Please, I don't know what is wrong, help me with it.I'm a newbie in CSS

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    position: relative;
}
img {
   width:238px;
   height:347px;
   display: block; 
}

body {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    padding-top: 6.88rem;
    padding-left: 15.19rem;
}

h1 {
color: #000;
font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
font-size: 2.25rem;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: normal;
letter-spacing: -0.10125rem;
}

.question {
color: #000;
font-family: Poppins;
font-size: 1.125rem;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.answer {
    width: 27.4375rem;
    height: 5.4375rem;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 13.44rem;
} 

.flex-container ~ div {
    position: relative;
    width: 276.684px;
    height: 469px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

p:first-child:not(footer > p):not(.question) {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 90%;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.gridContainer {
    display: grid;
    background: blue;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
    gap:2em;
    grid-template-areas:  "photo1 photo2 photo3"
                          "photo4 photo5 photo6"; 
}

div.photo1 {
    grid-area: photo1;
}

div.photo2 {
    grid-area: photo2;
}
div.photo3 {
    grid-area: photo3;
}  
div.phot4 {
    grid-area: photo4;
}
div.photo5 {
    grid-area: photo5;
} 
div.photo6 {
    grid-area: photo6;
}

footer p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Team Page</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=PT+Serif:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <main class="container">
        <div class="flex-container">
        <h1 class="flex1">The creative crew</h1>

        <div class="flex2">
        <p class="question">Who are we</p>
        <p class="answer">We are team of creatively diverse. driven. innovative individuals working in various locations from the world.</p>
        </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="gridContainer">
        <div class="photo1">
            <p>Product Owner</p>
            <img class="photo1" src="images/photo1.png">
            <p>Bill Mahoney</p>
        </div>

        <div class="photo2">
            <p>Art Director</p>
            <img class="photo2" src="images/photo2.png">
            <p>Saba Cabrera</p>
        </div>

        <div class="photo3">
            <p>Tech Lead</p>
            <img class="photo3" src="images/photo3.png">
            <p>Shae Le</p>
        </div>

        <div class="photo4">
            <p>UX Designer</p>
            <img class="photo4" src="images/photo4.png">
            <p>Skylah Lu</p>
        </div>

        <div class="photo5">
            <p>Developer</p>
            <img class="photo5" src="images/photo5.png">
            <p>Griff Richards</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="photo6">
            <p>DEverloper</p>
            <img class="photo6" src="images/photo6.png">
            <p>Stan John</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>
                HandWork of Adebimpe Abdulhamid Eniola
            </p> 
        </footer>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This rule is the problem `.flex-container ~ div`. It's setting the size of the grid container to be too small for the content.

Comment: Your footer element should be as well after the main element